# How do I get the Array value using Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I have this select

```
    $this->db->select('modulo_regra.regra_descricao');
    $this->db->from('modulo_regra');
    $this->db->where('modulo_regra.modulo_regra_id', id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

that return to me 2 elements in

```
  return $query->result_array();
```

Then I put the return in a Array

```
   $permissoes =array('areas' => $this->Regra_model->user_has($regra['regra_id']));
```

then I the $permissoes  to the session

```
   $this->session->set_userdata($permissoes);
```

So the real problem comes here.
when I'm loading the value from session

```
   $permissoes = array('areas');
   $permissoes = $this->session->userdata('areas');
```

this is its content:

```
array(2) ([0] => array(1) ([regra_descricao] => (string) clientes_cadastrar)
          [1] => array(1) ([regra_descricao] => (string) clientes_visualizar))
```

So i can't validate it with the in_array(), or other way...I would like to know if there is how if there is away to compare  the value in this array with one another variable

like

```
if(in_array('clientes_cadastrar',$permissoes)){}
```

I'm new on it... so sorry for the way i ask.

Comment: Instead of `$permissoes = array('areas');` try doing `$permissoes = array['areas'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't put entire array in return i.e

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   $return[] = $row->regra_descricao;
}
return $return;
```

THEN

you can easily find using:

```
if(in_array('clientes_cadastrar',$permissoes[**'areas'**])){}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

U can use the same scope.

```
 $this->db->select('modulo_regra.regra_descricao');
     $this->db->from('modulo_regra');
     $this->db->where('modulo_regra.modulo_regra_id', id);
     $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
       $permissoes = array['areas'];
    }

    $this->session->set_userdata($permissoes);
```